# Prevent leading zero in front of the letter grade?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, case

I use `CASE` statement in SQL to check the value for Grade column. If user entered 7 for example I stick leading 0 in front so value will be saved as `07`. Everything worked fine until we added K grade as an option in our app. Now if user enter K value will be saved as `0K`. Here is example of my SQL Case statement:

```
CASE 
   WHEN LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(GRADE))) = 0 THEN NULL 
   ELSE RIGHT('00'+ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(GRADE)),''),2) 
END
```

Code above is used in INSERT SELECT statement. I'm wondering if I can prevent leading zero when user enter K grade? Is that doable with modifying existing CASE statement? I have tried adding this:

```
WHEN GRADE = 'K' THEN 'K'
```

But this did not fix the problem, my INSERT statement failed. If anyone can help or knows better solution please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: what is the error message for failed insert?

Comment: @HABO after existing when.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way I would do it -

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'tb_Test')
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dbo.tb_Test
END

CREATE TABLE dbo.tb_Test (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, Grade NVARCHAR(10))

INSERT dbo.tb_Test (Grade)
VALUES ('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9'),('10'),('K')

SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(Grade) = 1 AND ISNUMERIC(Grade) = 1 THEN '0'+Grade 
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(Grade) = 1 THEN Grade 
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(Grade) = 0 THEN Grade END
  FROM dbo.tb_Test
```

Comment: You are suggesting to do this with temp tables? One thing that I didn't mention above Grade field is set to CHAR(2).

Comment: Not necessarily, it's just an example I put together for you to run on your machine. You could use the below for your use case. The datatype won't matter. You could use Char with the example.

CASE WHEN LEN(Grade) = 1 AND ISNUMERIC(Grade) = 1 THEN '0'+Grade ELSE Grade END

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    GRADE varchar(3)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('7'), (''),('03'),('001'),('K'), (NULL)
```

The query:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(GRADE))) = 0 THEN NULL
        WHEN GRADE NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN RIGHT('00' + GRADE, 3) 
        ELSE GRADE
        END As Res
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
Res
007
NULL
003
001
K
NULL
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/VQDWK8480)

Comment: No need for two leading zeros. My Grade field is set to CHAR(2). So only 0 leading zero can be entered if needed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I was basing my answer on your code... It should work the same with only one leading zero.